# Computing win probabilties for NFL teams

Tags: american-football, nfl, statistics, ranking

My fantasy team uses a playoff system that [Bill Simmons suggested a few years ago](http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/page2/story?page=simmons/060721). In order to study it, I'd like to run Monte Carlo simulations of last year's post-season. To do so, I need to be able to compute the win probability for a pair of teams given the site of the game. Note this is not a prediction against the spread, just the orders of one team winning. This format also means that I can't use Vegas's point spreads, money lines, etc. because I need to be able to make predictions for pairs of teams that didn't meet in real life.

I thought that it would be easy to find a suitable model online, but I haven't been able to. Here's what I've tried:

1. [AdvancedNFLStats](http://www.advancednflstats.com/): In principle they supply all the needed information but I've been unable to reproduce their results. You can see a long post from me at the end of the [week 7 team efficiency page](http://www.advancednflstats.com/2013/10/team-efficiency-rankings-week-7.html) that has gotten no replies. I would love to be able to get this model working.
2. [NFL Predictions](http://nfl-forecast.com/) uses stats from AdvancedNFLStats to run Monte Carlo paths through the post-season in some way that's slightly different from what AdvancedNFLStats does, but I can't find any info on the methodology.
3. [Simple Ranking System](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/blog/?p=37) a.k.a. simple rating system: is focused on predicting margin of victory, not probability. More info [here](http://smartfootball.com/chase-stuart/the-simple-rating-system-bringing-order-kinda-to-chaos). The creator gives a formula for computing win probabilities here, but it's not clear to me that the same constants can still be used.
4. [Jeff Sagarin's ELO ratings](http://sagarin.com/sports/nflsend.htm): also aimed at point spreads, not probabilities

[This page](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/blog/?p=691) seemed promising at first but I didn't get anywhere following up on all the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments section on [this page from Advanced NFL stats](http://www.advancednflstats.com/2013/12/game-probabilities-week-15.html) describes how to convert that website's weekly GWP values into win probabilities. A commenter named [James](http://www.blogger.com/profile/01838293735141324662) writes:

> The equation is: `(H*(1-A)*F) / (H*(1-A)*F+(1-H)*A*(1-F))`
>
> Where H is the GWP of the home team, A the GWP of the away team, and F
>   the home field advantage constant of 0.575.

Comment: There is no methodology I have seen for the NFL that makes any sort of sense.   The problem with predicting the NFL games is the fact that an individual's performance impact on a team cannot be predicted accurately and to make it even harder, an impact as to how it relates to playing another specific team.  For instance losing a starting tackle is a big deal, a bigger deal if backup stinks, even bigger if going against a great DE.  The problem is unlike baseball or basketball the loss value of a player is rather abstract statically, which makes your equation seem like nonsense.

Comment: Looking back on this as it came up in community you should really not accept your own answer when it is a poor answer.